# Magento 2 Custom table rates

Tags: magento2.3, shipping, shipping-methods, table-rates

we need to take charge -

$10 for any subtotal below $50,

$12 for any subtotal below $100,

$15 for any subtotal below $150,

and $150+ is free shipping all the time

And also FedEx

Free shipping and FedEx are working fine but table rate csv has condition **above** but our requirement is **below** when we are importing table rate then Table rate $150 is always showing.

Please check screenshot

[image]

Comment: Your table seems to be right, just change the last Shipping Price to 0 (150=>0) to have free shipping for 150+ orders

Comment: @MattiaKozianowski if above $150 then we do not want to use table rate.

Comment: have you already set the **minimum order amount** in the Free Shipping tab?

Comment: @MattiaKozianowski yes